# winston - how to log errors which cause node process to crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I have an express application, and there are some situations in which the whole node process will fail, mostly on ReferenceError.

I am wondering if there is a way to set up Winston to handle node crashing, and logging the issue that shows up in my console.

For example, I can force my application to crash by putting in a reference to `window`, resulting in:

`ReferenceError: window is not defined`

How can I get winston to log this?

In my app.js, I have the following set up for Winston, but it does not work:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      filename: `results.log`,
      timestamp: true,
      level: 'info',
      json: true,
      eol: 'n',
      handleExceptions: true,
      humanReadableUnhandledException: true
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});


process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   console.log('error');  // doesn't log this, 
});
```

Can someone help me out?

Basically, I am trying to log this error that comes up in my console if I make the app crash on purpose:

```
Listening on port 4200
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: window is not defined

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: window is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/Users/test/universal/dist/server/server.bundle.js:2135:9)
    at Wrapper_AppComponent.ngDoCheck (/AppModule/AppComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:22:53)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:31:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9354:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9447:48)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7337:24)
    at /Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6588:88
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ApplicationRef_.tick (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6588:42)
    at ApplicationRef_._loadComponent (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6566:18)
ERROR CONTEXT:

DebugContext {
  _view: 
   DebugAppView {
     clazz: [Function: View_AppComponent_Host0],
     componentType: 
      RenderComponentType {
        id: '39',
        templateUrl: '',
        slotCount: 0,
        encapsulation: 2,
        styles: [],
        animations: {} },
     type: 0,
     viewUtils: 
      ViewUtils {
        _renderer: [Object],
        _nextCompTypeId: 0,
        sanitizer: DomSanitizerImpl {} },
     parentView: null,
     parentIndex: null,
     parentElement: null,
     cdMode: 4,
     declaredViewContainer: null,
     viewContainer: null,
     numberOfChecks: 0,
     ref: ViewRef_ { _view: [Circular], _originalMode: 2 },
     renderer: 
      NodeDomRenderer {
        _rootRenderer: [Object],
        componentProto: [Object],
        _animationDriver: _NoOpAnimationDriver {},
        _styles: [],
        _contentAttr: null,
        _hostAttr: null,
        __rootRenderer: [Object] },
     _directRenderer: undefined,
     staticNodeDebugInfos: [ [Object] ],
     _currentDebugContext: [Circular],
     context: {},
     _hasExternalHostElement: true,
     _hostInjector: 
      NgModuleInjector {
        _parent: _NullComponentFactoryResolver {},
        _factories: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        bootstrapFactories: [Object],
        _destroyListeners: [Object],
        _destroyed: false,
        _CommonModule_0: CommonModule {},
        _ApplicationModule_1: ApplicationModule {},
        _NodeModule_2: NodeModule {},
        _NodeHttpModule_3: NodeHttpModule {},
        _NodeJsonpModule_4: NodeJsonpModule {},
        _UniversalModule_5: UniversalModule {},
        _InternalFormsSharedModule_6: InternalFormsSharedModule {},
        _FormsModule_7: FormsModule {},
        _ModalModule_8: ModalModule {},
        _CollapseModule_9: CollapseModule {},
        _StoreModule_10: StoreModule {},
        _EffectsModule_11: EffectsModule {},
        _InfiniteScrollModule_12: InfiniteScrollModule {},
        _PopoverModule_13: PopoverModule {},
        _Token_ROUTER_FORROOT_GUARD_14: 'guarded',
        _RouterModule_15: RouterModule {},
        _CacheService_16: [Object],
        _AppModule_17: [Object],
        _ErrorHandler_20: [Object],
        _ApplicationInitStatus_21: [Object],
        _TestabilityRegistry_22: [Object],
        _Testability_23: [Object],
        _ApplicationRef__24: [Object],
        _Token_Token__ngrx_store_reducer_62: [Function: reducers],
        _Token_Token_ngrx_store_reducer_63: [Function: reducers],
        __Dispatcher_60: [Object],
        _Reducer_64: [Object],
        _Token_Token__ngrx_store_initial_state_65: undefined,
        _Token_Token_ngrx_store_initial_state_66: [Object],
        _State_67: [Object],
        _Store_68: [Object],
        _EffectsSubscription_69: [Object],
        __ApplicationRef_25: [Object],
        __UrlSerializer_70: DefaultUrlSerializer {},
        __RouterOutletMap_71: [Object],
        __Token_ORIGIN_URL_44: 'localhost',
        __Token_REQUEST_URL_45: '/',
        __Token_appBaseHref_46: '/',
        __PlatformLocation_47: [Object],
        __Token_ROUTER_CONFIGURATION_72: {},
        __LocationStrategy_73: [Object],
        __Location_74: [Object],
        __Compiler_26: [Object],
        __NgModuleFactoryLoader_75: [Object],
        __Token_ROUTES_76: [Object],
        __Router_77: [Object],
        __NoPreloading_78: NoPreloading {},
        __PreloadingStrategy_79: NoPreloading {},
        _RouterPreloader_80: [Object],
        __ResponseOptions_54: [Object],
        __BrowserXhr_52: [Function: _noop],
        __XSRFStrategy_51: [Function: _noop],
        __XHRBackend_55: [Object],
        __RequestOptions_53: [Object],
        __Http_56: [Object],
        __HeaderPromotionsActions_94: HeaderPromotionsActions {},
        _CheckoutFormService_98: [Object],
        instance: [Object],
        __NodeSharedStylesHost_28: [Object],
        __Token_DocumentToken_29: [Object],
        __NodeDomEventsPlugin_30: [Object],
        __Token_HammerGestureConfig_31: [Object],
        __Token_EventManagerPlugins_32: [Object],
        __NodeEventManager_33: [Object],
        __EventManager_34: [Object],
        __AnimationDriver_35: _NoOpAnimationDriver {},
        __NodeDomRootRenderer_36: [Object],
        __DomRootRenderer_37: [Object],
        __RootRenderer_38: [Object],
        __DomSanitizer_39: DomSanitizerImpl {},
        __Sanitizer_40: DomSanitizerImpl {},
        __ViewUtils_41: [Object],
        __AuthService_87: [Object],
        __ProductActions_93: ProductActions {},
        __ActivatedRoute_91: [Object],
        __IterableDiffers_42: [Object],
        __KeyValueDiffers_43: [Object] },
     _hostProjectableNodes: [],
     _el_0: 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'app-root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: [Object],
        'x-attribsNamespace': {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': {},
        children: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        next: [Object] },
     _vc_0: 
      ViewContainer {
        index: 0,
        parentIndex: null,
        parentView: [Circular],
        nativeElement: [Object] },
     compView_0: 
      DebugAppView {
        clazz: [Function: View_AppComponent0],
        componentType: [Object],
        type: 1,
        viewUtils: [Object],
        parentView: [Circular],
        parentIndex: 0,
        parentElement: [Object],
        cdMode: 2,
        declaredViewContainer: null,
        viewContainer: null,
        numberOfChecks: 0,
        ref: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        _directRenderer: undefined,
        staticNodeDebugInfos: [Object],
        _currentDebugContext: [Object],
        _map_39: [Function],
        _map_40: [Function],
        _expr_41: [Object],
        _map_42: [Function],
        _expr_43: [Object],
        _expr_44: [Object],
        context: [Object],
        _el_0: [Object],
        _text_1: [Object],
        _el_2: [Object],
        _NgClass_2_3: [Object],
        _text_3: [Object],
        _el_4: [Object],
        _NgClass_4_3: [Object],
        _text_5: [Object],
        _text_6: [Object],
        _text_7: [Object],
        _anchor_8: [Object],
        _vc_8: [Object],
        _TemplateRef_8_5: [Object],
        _NgIf_8_6: [Object],
        _text_9: [Object],
        _el_10: [Object],
        _NgClass_10_3: [Object],
        _text_11: [Object],
        _el_12: [Object],
        _text_13: [Object],
        _el_14: [Object],
        _vc_14: [Object],
        _RouterOutlet_14_5: [Object],
        _text_15: [Object],
        _text_16: [Object],
        _el_17: [Object],
        _text_18: [Object],
        _anchor_19: [Object],
        _vc_19: [Object],
        _TemplateRef_19_5: [Object],
        _NgIf_19_6: [Object],
        _text_20: [Object],
        _text_21: [Object],
        _text_22: [Object],
        _anchor_23: [Object],
        _vc_23: [Object],
        _TemplateRef_23_5: [Object],
        _NgIf_23_6: [Object],
        _text_24: [Object],
        lastRootNode: null,
        allNodes: [Object],
        disposables: [Object] },
     _AppComponent_0_5: Wrapper_AppComponent { _changed: false, _changes: {}, context: [Object] },
     _el_1: 
      { type: 'comment',
        data: 'template bindings={}',
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null },
     lastRootNode: 
      { type: 'comment',
        data: 'template bindings={}',
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null },
     allNodes: [ [Object] ],
     disposables: [ [Function: bound disposeInlineArray], [Function] ] },
  _nodeIndex: 0,
  _tplRow: 0,
  _tplCol: 0 }

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/Users/test/universal/dist/server/server.bundle.js:2135:9)
    at Wrapper_AppComponent.ngDoCheck (/AppModule/AppComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:22:53)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:31:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9354:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9447:48)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7337:24)
    at /Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6588:88
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ApplicationRef_.tick (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6588:42)
    at ApplicationRef_._loadComponent (/Users/test/universal/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6566:18)
```

Here's the full code from the express app (using angular-universal):

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import './__2.1.1.workaround.ts'; // temporary until 2.1.1 things are patched in Core
import * as path from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import { createEngine } from 'angular2-express-engine';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.node';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { routes } from './server.routes';

const winston = require('winston');

const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      filename: `results.log`,
      timestamp: true,
      level: 'info',
      json: true,
      eol: 'n',
      handleExceptions: true,
      humanReadableUnhandledException: true
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});


process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   console.log('error');  // doesn't log this, 
});

// App

const app = express();

const ROOT = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;

/**
 * enable prod mode for production environments
 */
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

/**
 * Express View
 */
app.engine('.html', createEngine({}));
app.set('views', path.join(ROOT, 'client'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

/**
 * Enable compression
 */
app.use(compression());

/**
 * serve static files
 */
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(ROOT, 'client'), { index: false }));

const cache = {};

function ngApp(req, res) {
  let baseUrl = '/';
  let url = req.originalUrl || '/';
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1000');
  if (cache[url]) {
    res.status(200).send(cache[url]);
    return;
  }
  res.render('index', {
    req,
    res,
    ngModule: AppModule,
    preboot: {
      appRoot: ['app-root'],
      uglify: true,
      buffer: true
    },
    async: false,
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    requestUrl: req.originalUrl,
    originUrl: req.hostname
  },
  (err, html) => {
    cache[url] = html;
    res.status(200).send(html);
  });
}

/**
 * use universal for specific routes
 */
app.get('/', ngApp);
routes.forEach(route => {
  app.get(`/${route}`, ngApp);
  app.get(`/${route}/*`, ngApp);
});

/**
 * if you want to use universal for all routes, you can use the '*' wildcard
 */

app.get('*', function (req: any, res: any) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  const pojo = { status: 404, message: 'No Content' };
  const json = JSON.stringify(pojo, null, 2);
  res.status(404).send(json);
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it still doesn't work because I am crashing my app on purpose with reference to window. If I crash my app on purpose, I can see the console logs the reason.  How can I get that error message into my log?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since my original answer didn't help, I ran your code and it properly logged uncaught exceptions with the following modification:

`process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   logger.log("error", "qqq")
   console.log('error');  // just prints the word 'error',
});`

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please look at my updated question?  Basically I am trying to get the error that is shown in my console into a log file.  THanks

Comment: Thanks Alon Oz.  I put in the line you mentioned, and also added this ErrorHandler.  So, it crashes and throws that big error message I posted in the console.  However, an exceptions.log file is not created :(

Comment: I'm using the latest node.  Maybe that is why I am having issues?  I tried with node 6 and it works, but with 7.x it doesn't.  :O

Comment: try bunyan, the "other" logging module. :-)